# error converting image by imagemagick

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick

when I try to convert via php my svg file to ex. png file i get this error:

```
    $filename = '507e6221c9f0f.svg';
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob($content);

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ blob.c/BlobToImage/347' in..
```

however when I do this via commend line everything is ok. I would use php `exec()` command, but I'm using PHP + IIS server, so I don't wanna to grant permission to use cmd.exe by IUSR user (the IIS user)

can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that imagemagick does not know how to handle that file. Some things you can check:

1) check the svg file manually.
2) check if you are using inkscape or rsvg.
3) try a shell command (assuming you are on linux) like 'convert 507e6221c9f0f.svg image.jpg'

May be post output here so ther someone can check it out.

Comment: as I wrote before I can convert image from command line but can not from php script.

Comment: Oops! sorry about ignoring. You can convert it in cmd and you are on windows. Can you check $content has actually the file content. May be provide full path of image to file_get_contents.